# Which IPC is supported in Ubuntu 12.04: POSIX or System V

Tags: ipc

How do I know which type of IPC is supported in Ubuntu 12.04: System V  or POSIX

Is there any command to get this ?

Answer (score 4):

System V is fully supported on all Linux kernels, POSIX IPC since kernel 2.6. So Ubuntu 12.04 supports both. Others have described it better than I can:

- [System V IPC vs POSIX IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582968/system-v-ipc-vs-posix-ipc)
- [Comparing Unix/Linux IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404604/comparing-unix-linux-ipc)

[ipcs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcs.1.html) is an interesting command for poking around your SysV IPC facilities (shm segments, semaphores and message queues).